# Github GraphQL API: How can I find out which fields are searchable?

Tags: rest, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

When I run the query:

```
{
   "query": "{user(login: \"furknyavuz\") {repositories(first: 50, isPrivate: false) {nodes {name url}}}}"
}
```

I getting the following error:

```
{
"data": null,
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Field 'repositories' doesn't accept argument 'isPrivate'",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 51
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I can see isPivate is field of Repository object but I'm unable to search with it.

I'm not expecting to search with all fields of the object, but critical question is, how can I see which fields are searchable or indexable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isPrivate` is a field of `Repository` object but [`repositories`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/user/#repositories) inside [User object](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/user/) is of type [RepositoryConnection](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/repositoryconnection/) and [`repositories`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/user/#repositories) connection item has the following argument/type :

- affiliations  [RepositoryAffiliation]
- after String
- before    String
- first Int
- isFork    Boolean
- isLocked  Boolean
- last  Int
- orderBy   RepositoryOrder
- privacy   RepositoryPrivacy

[`RepositoryPrivacy`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/enum/repositoryprivacy/) is an enum with two values : PUBLIC and PRIVATE.

the following request will return private repo :

```
{
  user(login: "furknyavuz") {
    repositories(first: 50, privacy:PRIVATE) {
      nodes {
        name
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in [the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), if you type <kbd>CTRL+space</kbd> you will have the schema listing with types :

[image]

Also, <kbd>CTRL+space</kbd> again after ":" will gives you the enum values :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Autocomplete:**

Navigate to Github's [GraphQL API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/). This is a Graph*i*QL interface that lets you write your queries and run in them in real time. One of the neat features of GraphiQL is that includes an auto-complete feature. When you're typing the arguments for a field, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and a list of possible arguments will pop up. This works for fields too.

**The docs:**

You can also view the documentation for the schema by hitting the `Docs` link in the upper right corner of the interface. This will bring up a list of all possible fields, including what arguments they take. There's also a schema reference page [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/).

**GraphQL:**

Lastly, you can actually just ask the GraphQL endpoint yourself. For example, running this query will list all types for the schema and the arguments used by each one:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      inputFields {
        name
        description
        type {
          name
        }
        defaultValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```